# play mp3 issue in ionic 1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using `cordova-plugin-media` plugin but I cannot play audio using this plugin.

I am passing src as:

```
file://Users/octal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/76B662A8-4F13-4101-BE9E-81E0CF7AC6C8/data/Containers/Data/Application/2816A672-FD98-4993-8BE8-0A506E5BF342/Library/NoCloud/M-5b22017edb5e8.mp3
```

or

```
cdvfile://Users/octal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/76B662A8-4F13-4101-BE9E-81E0CF7AC6C8/data/Containers/Data/Application/2816A672-FD98-4993-8BE8-0A506E5BF342/Library/NoCloud/M-5b22017edb5e8.mp3
```

Neither of them is working.